# JQuery Filter Numbers Of A String

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

How do you filter only the numbers of a string?

```
Example Pseudo Code:
number = $("thumb32").filternumbers()
number = 32
```

Comment: Could you give some example data? dkwlj-32-fjkij-ff0-33?

Comment: Please read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq Questions should be *questions*. And the more effort you put into your question, the better the quality and quantity of answers you'll recent (and the more respect for the venue you're showing).

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for this - just plain old JavaScript [regex replacement](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

`var number = yourstring.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')`

This will get rid of anything that's not [0-9]

Edit: Here's a small function to extract all the numbers (as actual numbers) from an input string. It's not an exhaustive expression but will be a good start for anyone needing.

```
function getNumbers(inputString){
    var regex=/\d+\.\d+|\.\d+|\d+/g, 
        results = [],
        n;

    while(n = regex.exec(inputString)) {
        results.push(parseFloat(n[0]));
    }

    return results;
}

var data = "123.45,34 and 57. Maybe add a 45.824 with 0.32 and .56"
console.log(getNumbers(data));
// [123.45, 34, 57, 45.824, 0.32, 0.56];
```

Comment: Why is regex so hard?  It looks so foreign and my brain just seems to shut down immediately because it gets very overwhelmed by a lot of punctuation... and symbols, if I don't know their meaning but know they mean something...  Why do I have to look this up every time?  The info just doesn't stick in my head no matter what...

Comment: ^ Welcome to the club.

Comment: Hello. But for number like 12.5, 20.3. They return 125 and 203?

Comment: @MinhAnh - This just just a very basic example for the question at the time. I've added a little bit extra for the case that you've mentioned.

Comment: @gloomy.penguin pretty sure 90+% of us use cheat sheets, because yeah, VERY complicated regular expressions are. (I was 16 years into my career before I even attempted to get my head around them.)  :)

Comment: @gloomy.penguin This particular regex could be simpler: `\d*\.?\d+` (optional digits, optional dot, at least one digit).

Comment: /(not )?to be/i

Answer (score 26):

Not really jQuery at all:

```
number = number.replace(/\D/g, '');
```

That regular expression, `/\D/g`, matches any non-digit. Thus the call to `.replace()` replaces all non-digits (all of them, thanks to "g") with the empty string.

*edit* — if you want an actual **number* value, you can use `parseInt()` after removing the non-digits from the string:

```
var number = "number32"; // a string
number = number.replace(/\D/g, ''); // a string of only digits, or the empty string
number = parseInt(number, 10); // now it's a numeric value
```

If the original string may have no digits at all, you'll get the numeric non-value `NaN` from `parseInt` in that case, which may be as good as anything.

Comment: You might want a `parseInt` in there?

Comment: @sje397: Maybe, maybe not -- with the quality of the question, we have no idea whether he/she wants a number of a string containing only digits.

Comment: Maybe = maybe not = might ? ;)