# How to extract an element from id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Question:** How to extract element from id?

**HTML :**

```
<div class="product">
    <p id="price1">99,00</p>
</div>
<div class="product">
    <p id="price2">101,00</p>
</div>
<div class="product">
    <p id="price3">50,00</p>
</div>
<div class="product">
    <p id="price4">1,99</p>
</div>
<div class="product">
    <p id="price5">2,01</p>
</div>
```

**JS :**

```
var sumPrice = 0;

$(".product").click(function() {    

    if ( i = 1) sumPrice += parseFloat($( "#price" + i ).text())
    else if ( i = 2) sumPrice += parseFloat($( "#price" + i ).text())
    else if ( i = 3) sumPrice += parseFloat($( "#price" + i ).text())
    else if ( i = 4) sumPrice += parseFloat($( "#price" + i ).text())
    else if ( i = 5) sumPrice += parseFloat($( "#price" + i ).text())

    $(".total").val(sumPrice);
});
```

I'm trying to get different prices and summarize. Now I add only the first value.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2gczfnph/)

Comment: what is 'i' in your javascript?

Comment: You don't need any conditions in your handler. Just `parseFloat( $(this).text() )` - you'll probably have to replace your commas with periods, and then back again when outputting it - [something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/2gczfnph/3/)

Comment: @billyonecan, thank you a lot for the helpful comments, I even learned a bit myself with the different ways of getting prop id. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
$(".product").click(function() {   
    sumPrice += parseFloat($( this ).text())
    $(".total").val(sumPrice);
});
```

A working [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2gczfnph/9/).
As @bilyonecan also notes, you might want to replace the `,` with a `.` such that the value is parsed correctly to float. You can do that using `.replace(',', '.')` a simple replace on the `$( this ).text()` making the code:

```
$(".product").click(function() {   
    sumPrice += parseFloat($( this ).text().replace(',', '.'))
    $(".total").val(sumPrice);
});
```

---

If you really want to find out the `id` of the clicked item you can do that using:

```
this.id; //gives the id of the clicked element. (javascript style)
$(this).prop('id') //or jQuery style (id of clicked element) 
$(this).children().first().prop('id'); //gives the id of the first child element (<p> in your case)
```

---

### `$this` in jQuery / Javascript

The object `$this` is the object where the function or listener belongs to, and in your case it is the object that is being clicked and has this click handler. `$this` is very convenient and meant to be used in this way such that you do not need ids with counters and more of this kind of work arounds.

Comment: That seems more correct. The fiddle suggests that this is the desired behavour.

Comment: Maybe add a segment about `this` in jQuery's click function - how the element clicked binds itself to the function. That seems to be the part OP's not familiar with.

Comment: @Neta, good point, improve it if you like, I am not very good in explaining the exact nature of `$this` I am afraid.

Comment: Change `$(".total").val(sumPrice);` to `$(".total").val(parseFloat(sumPrice).toFixed(2));` to show decimal places too.

Comment: Thanks. It's really helpful. What if I change HTML? Should I use `this`? [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2gczfnph/10/)

Comment: Ok. Is there any universal method for this replace? Look at this: [jsfiddle.net/2gczfnph/12/](https://jsfiddle.net/2gczfnph/12/)

Comment: @rylko sure, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460595/jquery-filter-numbers-of-a-string You will need regular expressions.

Comment: @bas-van-stein thank you a lot. My final code: [jsfiddle.net/2gczfnph/13/](https://jsfiddle.net/2gczfnph/13/). There is only one problem in 3rd row `3rd product: 50,00`.

Comment: @rylko you are welcome, you can use this: https://jsfiddle.net/2gczfnph/17/ I am using the fact that you want to remove everything till the `:`.