# Extract value from dropdown in jquery need only numeric value

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, split

Hello everyone I am getting the value from dropdownlist using jquery
here is my jquery code

```
var priceValue = $("#ddlprice option:selected").text();
```

and i am getting value 
**Valvet ($100)**

but i want only 100 from this value so how can I extract the exact value from it.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex using javascript to return just numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183903/regex-using-javascript-to-return-just-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expression to get the number

```
/\d+/g this will search for number in a given string
```

```js
var priceValue = "Valvet ($100)";


console.log(/\d+/g.exec(priceValue)[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

if the value is 100 like this

```
<select id="ddlprice">
  <option value="100">Valvet ($100)</option>
</select>
```

then you get the value using `val()` like this `$("#ddlprice").val();`  to get the value

if your option is written like this `<option>Valvet ($100)</option>` or like this `<option value="Valvet ($100)">Valvet ($100)</option>` 
then you can use the function below from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460595/jquery-filter-numbers-of-a-string) which will print only the numbers in a string.

```
function getNumbers(inputString){
    var regex=/\d+\.\d+|\.\d+|\d+/g, 
        results = [],
        n;

    while(n = regex.exec(inputString)) {
        results.push(parseFloat(n[0]));
    }

    return results;
}
var priceValue = $("#ddlprice option:selected").text(); 
console.log(getNumbers(priceValue));
```